# WordPress Custom Post template won't load

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I created a custom post, and made a template file named single-postname.php

I can't get the template file to load, before I would just get re-directed back to the homepage, but after flushing the .htaccess file I just get a blank page.

I tried removing and adding the post again, changed the permalinks a couple times, and changed the theme, nothing seems to work. Is there anything else I can do to try forcing WordPress to look for the file again?

The register_post_type

```
$labels = array( 
    'name' => _x( 'Conversations', 'conversation' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Conversation', 'conversation' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'conversation' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Conversation', 'conversation' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Conversation', 'conversation' ),
    'new_item' => _x( 'New Conversation', 'conversation' ),
    'view_item' => _x( 'View Conversation', 'conversation' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Search Conversations', 'conversation' ),
    'not_found' => _x( 'No conversations found', 'conversation' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No conversations found in Trash', 'conversation' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Conversation:', 'conversation' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Conversations', 'conversation' ),
);

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'description' => 'conversation between users on the site',
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'excerpt', 'author', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ),

    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,
    //'menu_icon' => 'http://findicons.com/files/icons/2229/social_media_mini/24/google_talk.png',
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post'
);

register_post_type( 'conversation', $args );
```

Filename = single-conversation.php

Comment: There is no such template as `single-postname.php`, you most probably mean `single-posttype.php`? If so show us the custom post type code & the name of your template file.

Comment: Over the weekend, it started working, must of been a cache issue, but just so this question could help people, if you write an answer explaining the naming of files and I'll make it the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the template hierarchy, if you're looking to output an archive of all posts under custom post type "xyz" then you would create a file called "archive-xyz.php" and put it in your page-templates directory. If you're looking to output a single post under the custom post type "xyz" then WordPress will look for a file called "single-xyz.php."

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

There's my attempt at elucidation :)